# Generating units with an algorithm

Tags: statistics, simulation

Give an efficient algorithm for generating the first $T = 20$ time units to a Poisson process not homogeneous, whose intensity function is given by

$\lambda(t) = \begin{cases}\frac{t}{5} & \text{if } t\in[0, 5) \\
1+5(t-5) & \text{if } t\in[5,10)
 \end{cases}$

Can you help me? Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you approximate, or should this be essentially exact? If it needs to be exact then you will need to explicitly calculate the density of $t$ conditioned on $t>t_0$ for any $t_0 \geq 0$, which will require some calculus. Once you have that the problem boils down to applying the probability integral transformation. (By the way, your rate is not specified on the entire time interval of interest...)